# How can I hide cell contents in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm working through a tutorial in Google Colaboratory, and the author has handily hidden some of the solutions cells.  When you click the hidden cell, it expands and becomes visible.  How can I hide the cells?

An example is in this tutorial:  [Creating and Manipulating Tensors](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/creating_and_manipulating_tensors.ipynb?hl=en).

[image: Hidden Cells example]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

None of the other answers worked for me. You can collapse cells by adding this to the top of the cell "#@title" and then double clicking on the white space that appears to the right of it.

```
#@title Your Title Here
```

Comment: note: I think this is a workaround but doens't do it the way that the question asks.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to do it without seeing the cell (as they contain spoilers). This necessitates seeing the cell to edit it.

Comment: For me the answer was "double click on the white space to the right". Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to hide everything below, you'll need to have a cell with a title below the cells you want to hide

Answer (score 22):

1. You right-click on the area on the left of the cell (below the "Play" button) and choose "Add a form"
2. You can enter a title for your cell after the `#@title` keyword (first line in your cell code)
3. Right-click again in the same place and choose "Form > Hide code"

Comment: This is a useful answer to a different question.  It doesn't create a "hidden cell [that, when clicked], it expands and becomes visible".

Answer (score 15):

The black triangle, that makes it possible to fold and unfold sections, appears when you create a section (which is equivalent to creating a title).

You can create a section by creating a text cell that starts with `# <your section title>`.

This is how you create title in Markdown: `# This is a title` `## This is a smaller title` `### This is even a smaller title`...

You can fold and unfold sections by clicking on the triangle next to their title.

This image illustrates how to create a section:

[image: This image illustrates how to create a part]

This image is the result of the previous image (**note the magic triangle on the left**):

[image: This image is the result of the previous image note the triangle on the left]

Comment: Right. And any number of #s appears to work. And they nest, with a text cell that has n #s, collapsing all following cells with more than n #s.

Comment: This is the right answer: 1. it answers the question posed; 2. it explains how to implement the answer; and 3. it explains why the answer is correct.  The accepted answer is not correct for non-markdown cells (`adding this to the top of the cell "#@title"` does not make code cells collapsible) and doesn't explain why it works.

Comment: This is the right answer in order to hide one or more cells, BUT one must create a text cell and create a heading therein. It should be added that such a cell with a heading will hide all cells to the next cell with a heading.
The ``#@title`` is the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52981699/2529666) if one does want to make a single code cell collapsible without creating any additional cells. This will also be done by the system if the user selects multiple cells and chooses 'hide' from the context menu, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368117/2529666).

Answer (score 8):

I realise this question was posted some time ago but as a newbie to Google Colab myself I thought it would be helpful to share what I have found useful when 'collapsing' sections of code and generally organising code within my notebooks.

To add a collapsible section: proceed title with `'#'`, all code below will fall within this title and can be collapsed. I.e. `'#Import libraries'` will produce:

[image: Collapsible Colab title]

To add collapsible sub-sections (within the main header) simply add another `'#'`, and so on. So, `'##Check tf version'` would fall within '#Import libraries'

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The most easiest way is to define "section" between your code cells. Then next to the title there an arrow using which you can hide all cells inside the section

Hide using sections:

[image: hide using sections]

---

Select multiple cells using SHIFT and your mouse click.

then do right click to get the Hide Cell option like this

Show hide cell option:

[image: show hide cell option]

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a text cell
2. Write text beginning with a #
   i.e #text
3. Shift + Enter

The text cell will become a collapse/expand tool and the cells below this text cell can be collapsed/expanded now

Answer (score 3):

To collapse/hide all cells without seeing them,

go to: menu → view → collapse sections, and click.

Answer (score 2):

You can click at the “Triangle” in front of “Solution” heading. It will toggle between hide/show.

Comment: The question is asking for how to create a cell that is toggleable, not how to toggle a cell

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking, how to replicate this:
What you can see in your screenshot is just what happens if you put text cells with a markup headings in between your code cells to create sections in your notebook. 
In this case that would simply be a text cell containing just `# Solution` above the two code cells.

You can hide and show the sections by clicking on the little triangle.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out...but it is actually quite easy.

Manually collapse the section you would like manually, then go to "file/save". It will preserve the layout (including which section is collapsed) next time you open the notebook.

Hope a bit helpful!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! I do want to add some info on what colab does behind the scenes. When you save the notebook after you've collapsed the sections you want to have collapsed by default when the notebook is opened again, Colab adds specific notebook metadata to the .ipynb file. If you open the .ipynb file with a text editor and look towards the bottom of the file, you will see `"colab": {"provenance": [], "collapsed_sections": ["PPhIBYt_kGYV"], "toc_visible": true}`. Colab adds the `id` of the first cell of every collapsed section to the notebook's metadata.

Answer (score 1):

To hide multiple cells.

1. Create Text cell, by clicking +Text button.
2. Give a title, like "# Setup".
3. Then on the left, the triangle button will come, to hide all cells below that.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one mention metadata setups to hide a cell code in form environment, I will share my findings.

This use case is if you want to make a notebook file in GitHub that has a banner to be opened in Colab, and you want the notebook to hide some cell.

---

To hide a code cell you need to:

1. Make the cell into form cell by adding `#@title` on the very top of the cell.
2. add below metadata to the cell (you need to use plain text editor to do this):

   ```json
      "metadata": {
       "cellView": "form",
       "colab": {}
      },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to collapse and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to expand

Answer (score 0):

just go on the top left corner (table of contents) then tap on +section. now on the left of the "new section" on your notebook there is a sign for the collapse of the cell and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the side bar with the play button

[image: hide code]

Answer (score 0):

In the code area at Colab, add this line at the top

```
#@title don't show code till dblclick
```

your own code will be below:

```
print("hello world")
```

And After running the code area, you can see the title in Larger font at the top. Just double-click to hide/unhide
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you need to hide code in your personal notebook, click at the gray vertical line (with 'run button') of the current cell and then check '**Hide code**'

Answer (score -1):

Here is the hot key for ya:

```
ctrl + "
```

After setting up the text part in Colab like what others have said, you can press **control and quote** key at the same time and collapse whichever cell/section you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just Make a new text cell and when writing the text include a # in the front it will make it a collapsable cell

without #

[image: 1]

Use # infront of the title you want to enter and you are done

UPVOTE PLS

with #

[image: 2]